# Android - Change Values and save them

Tags: android, save

I want to give the User of my App the decision to change the font and the Textsize. But how can I save it, so the Textsize or the font is set as default, if the user changes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save users choice in Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sPref;
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor ed = sPref.edit();
String putString = myEdText.getText().toString(); //users choice
ed.putString("SAVED_TEXT", putString);
ed.commit();
```

and then read from it

```
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedText = sPref.getString("SAVED_TEXT", "");

and then dinamicly change properties of TextView
TextView myTextView = (TextView)fidViewByid(...); 
myTextView.setTextSize(Float.valueOf(putString));
```

Also you can save data to local DB (sql lite);
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences

Save it on change
Read it on create